# Java abstract class pass either of the child object that extend the base class

Tags: java, abstract

I have an abstract class where I want to create a method that can be passed either of the child instances that extend it.

For example:

```
abstract class base
{
       public void doSomething(Child1 or Child2){
       }
}
class Child1 extends base
{
    public void somefunc(){
        doSomething(Child1);
    }
}
class Child2 extends base
{
    public void somefunc(){
        doSomething(Child2);
    }
}
```

I feel like there are multiple ways to get around it. Is it possible to get an idea of what are the possible ways? I definitely dont want to create the same function in all the child classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is what you're looking for.

```
abstract class base
{
       public void doSomething(base obj){
       }
}
class Child1 extends base
{
    public void somefunc(){
        doSomething(this);
    }
}
class Child2 extends base
{
    public void somefunc(){
        doSomething(this);
    }
}
```

Then, if you want override `doSomething` in your child classes.
In fact, you don't even need the `base` parameter and to pass `this`, you already have an implicit reference to `this`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if the parameter passed to `doSomething` is supposed to be `this`, or a separate object of the same type. In the first case, peter.petrov's answer is what you want. In the second case, the standard way around this is to make `Base` generic and to use a recursive bound.

```
abstract class Base<T extends Base<T>> {

    public void doSomething(T t) {}
}

class Child1 extends Base<Child1> {

    public void someFunc() {
        Child1 child1 = new Child1();
        doSomething(child1);
    }
}

class Child2 extends Base<Child2> {

    public void someFunc() {
        Child2 child2 = new Child2();
        doSomething(child2);
    }
}
```

Comment: although @peter.petrov will probably solve my problem...i like your answer on this also.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ideas behind inheritance is to share behaviour amongst classes of the same abstract type.

So if you want the same behaviour for all subtypes of your base class, implement the method in your base class. You don't need to pass the object reference, use the `this` keyword.

If you want different behaviours in your sub classes, declare the method abstract in your base class and implement each of the behaviours in the various sub classes.